# How to use Sphinx Search with concurrency?

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine, sphinx

I have a large database (100M rows) indexed by SphinxSearch. Each search takes 0.1-0.5s. However, if I run 10 searches concurrently, they take 20s on average.

Is it the expected behaviour of SphinxSearch?

Should I adjust the config or move to another search engine for concurrency?

My config file is simple:

```
searchd
{
    listen          = 9312
    listen          = 9306:mysql41
    pid_file        = /var/searchd.pid
    read_timeout        = 30
    log         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
    query_log       = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the expected behaviour of SphinxSearch?

It heavily depends on the number of CPUs. If you have more than 10 physical CPUs then latency degradation from 0.5 sec to 20 sec by increasing the concurrency from 1 to 10 is definitely not expected. In this case first of all make sure all your CPUs are busy under the concurrency load. If it's not - depending on your Sphinx version and multi-tasking mode let it run with more threads.

> Should I adjust the config or move to another search engine for concurrency?

I recommend [Manticore Search](https://manticoresearch.com/) as:

- it's open source - https://github.com/manticoresoftware/manticoresearch/
- it's the only fork of Sphinx and if you are familiar with Sphinx in general it shouldn't be a problem to migrate
- hundreds of bugs have been fixed
- the multi-tasking mode is completely different (coroutines)